# How can i see if current user is admin of facebook canvas app

Tags: facebook, permissions, admin, facebook-authentication

I am working in a facebook canvas app which has an edit settings page. I need to protect that page so only the application administrators have access to it.

I couldn´t find any information about how to do this. This should be a pretty basic feature.

Any ideas?

Comment: What technologies do you use? PHP, Asp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### FQL

```
SELECT uid, page_id, type from page_admin WHERE page_id=YOUR_APP_ID AND uid=me()
```

### Graph

Alternatively, you can get the Pages/Applications that the user is admin of using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts
```

Your app will require the `manage_pages` permission. For more details see:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#page-login

Answer (score 1):

how about storing admin id's in a db, etc ,get the id of the currenly logged in user ..compare and decide .